# criar arquivo de texto em android na memoria interna Xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Bom estou tentando salvar um ip do servidor onde esta meu bd mas não estou conseguindo pois não da acesso suficiente para gravar o arquivo de texto na memoria interna do celular, alguem tem alguma dica de como posso fazer isso, não quero usar SDcard pois não são todas as pessoas que usam o mesmo desta forma meu app ficaria inutilizavel, aguardo resposta de como eu posso gravar um arquivo de texto na memoria internar do celular

Comment: Tente detalhar um pouco mais a sua pergunta

Comment: ok, vou alterar o post

Answer (score 0):

A biblioteca SQLite.NET que o Xamarin recomenda é um ORM muito básico que permite armazenar e recuperar facilmente objetos no banco de dados SQLite local em um dispositivo Android. ORM significa Object Relational Mapping - uma API que permite salvar e recuperar "objetos" de um banco de dados sem escrever instruções SQL.

De qualquer uma das formas a sua pergunta ainda está um pouco vasta de modo que não consigo dar uma resposta mais detalhadas.